# Assign names to applications without Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I have an application in the service fabric and I'm going to upload another one.
I wonder if it's possible to assign different names to each application.
With an application, I access using the address:

```
http://sf-spartan.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
```

You can configure for access to look like this:?

http://application1.sf-spartan.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com

or

http://sf-spartan.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/application1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/new-servicefabricapplication?view=azureservicefabricps). Use the `ApplicationName` argument to define it.
Every application instance you create must in fact have a unique name.

You can reach your application instance through its url by using a [reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy). (either the built-in one, or a custom one like Traefik)

Usually, the application and service name are part of the url, e.g.:
`http://mycluster.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:19081/MyApp/MyService`

This does require a [web based communication listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-create-dotnet-app).

Event more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-remove-applications#create-the-application).